# NullPointerException in TextView used in Alertdialog setView

Tags: android

[image: LOgCat..]In Android in litemitemclick I am using this piece of code:

```
TextView tvofpostedText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postedgtext);
    @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                        long arg3) {



    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        DemoPage2.this);
                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(DemoPage2.this);

                final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(
                        R.layout.layoutforalertdialog, null);

                // builder.setMessage("" + s.get(pos))
                try {
                    tvofpostedText.setText("username:" + s.get(pos));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
                builder.setMessage("" + username + (CharSequence) s.get(pos))
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setTitle("post Detail")
                        .setView(textEntryView)

                        .setPositiveButton("View Comments",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        // ListViewActivity.this.finish();

                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNeutralButton("Post Comments",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                tvofpostedText.setText("username:" + s.get(pos));
            }

        });
```

**s** is an `ArrayList`. I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the line `tvofpostedText.setText("username:" + s.get(pos));`. At least *"username"* should have been set as text even if `s.get(pos)` is null. Please help me out.In the logcat i am getting null pointer exception.tvofpostedText is comming null.Plese HELP>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've got two possibilites, neither of which anyone here can determine with the code you've given.

1. tvofpostedText is null.
2. s is null.

Figure out which one is null and fix that. You don't show where either of these is declared, but that's the only two possibilities given the line it's crashing at.

Comment: tvofpostedText  i comming null.but How do i fix that.

Comment: Assign something to it? Give it a value? If it's a view inside your layout, use `findViewById()` or something like it to acquire a reference to it.

Comment: Your question has been answered. I don't need the logcat, the answer is right here. tvofpostedText is null. Give it a value.

Comment: i got the solution...i will be TextView tvofpostedText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.postedgtext); and it should be instantiated inside the dialog as the textview is a view of the dialog layout......cool....

Answer (score 1):

You should post your logcat so we can help you figure out exactly what is wrong. Where is tvofpostedText mentioned earlier? In which layout is it in? I would suggest you set it by findViewById() before you modify it.